# cannot infer type on match arm

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to implement a custom deserializer for a type, but I cannot make this work.

```
match de::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)
    .map_err(|_| None)
    .ok()
{
    Some(s) if s == "1" => Ok(Some(true)),
    _ => Ok(None),
}
```

The error is "cannot infer type" at Some(s).

The weird thing is if I do

```
let s = de::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
```

it knows that `s` is `&str`. Is there an easy was to tell the compiler that Some(s) is Option<&str>? And why doesn't it know automatically in this case?

Comment: Just remove the `map_err` line. It does nothing.

Comment: @drewtato that was a mistake on my part when copying the code, however, removing it still not solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new [**let-else**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiM1qvf0siDAxWVRPEDHfkWAKUQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.rust-lang.org%2Frust-by-example%2Fflow_control%2Flet_else.html&usg=AOvVaw0V_bg-OflR7DS9pt7qbsk2&opi=89978449) syntax makes your program not only clearer but also gets rid of your `cannot infer type` problem:

```
let rslt = de::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer);
let Result::Ok(s) = rslt else { return rslt; };
if s == "1" {
    Ok(Some(true))
} else {
    Ok(None)
}
```